# Filtering query pagination

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I got this router pagination

UserService

```js
 get(perPage, page)  {
    return http.get(`/api/users?page_size=` + perPage + '&page=' + page);
  },
```

Fetching

```js
 const listUsers = async () => {
      const result = await UserService.get(10, props.page);
      userList.value = result.data.users;
      totalPages.value = result.data.total_pages
    }
```

I tried adding this search filter method

```js
 const searchUser = computed(() => {
      return userList.value.filter((item) => item.email.match(searchValue.value));
    })
```

But I am having issue here - it is returning only the values from current page, for e.g if Im on page 1 and I search an item that is on page 2, it wont show it unless I click next page and Im on page 2. Is there way to return everything on first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to search in all records, you need to do the searching on server side. Just like pagination properties add your filter parameters to query parameters. Of course you can add more than one parameter but for your example something like

**"api/users?email=searchTextHere&page_size=10&page=0"**

will work (I prefer limit and offset instead of page_size and page)

Comment: Thanks, so there's no way to do this properly just on frontend side?

Comment: Yes, if you want to search something in a data set, you need whole dataset not a part of it. When you do the pagination you are getting only a part of your data set. This is actually right thing to do. Because you may have millions of users and it will be almost impossible to fetch or render in frontend. But as you realized there is a trade off. Which is searching in a part of a dataset is not giving you all the matching data. So we do it in the backend as I explained in my answer.  Since database has all the data its easy to add one more where clause to the sql query.